# Uncaught ReferenceError: AV_ga is not defined

Tags: javascript, web, adobecreativesdk

I have been trying to implement the Adobe image editor UI in a rails project however I am running into a problem. I also get the same error when implementing Adobe's web-getting-started-samples project so I don't understand what is going wrong.

codesample of the getting-started-sample can be found here:
https://github.com/CreativeSDK/web-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui/image-editor-ui-jquery

When I click on edit, the image pops up in the adobe UI however none of the functionality works. When I press on frames or stickers or enhance a loading wheel appears but thats it. In the console the following is logged:

Uncaught ReferenceError: AV_ga is not defined

Does anybody know what is going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Without seeing any code I doubt anyone will know what's going on.

Comment: in the getting-started-sample-project it doesnt work properly either code can be found here: https://github.com/CreativeSDK/web-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui/image-editor-ui-jquery

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions listed on that page (register the app, replace the client id, `npm install`)?

Comment: yup that is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. But i uploaded to a server, the same that i put in the configuration. The server was https instead of http, so i change the dk for this one `https://dme0ih8comzn4.cloudfront.net/imaging/v3/editor.js`

Also, make sure of running `sudo npm install` on the folder before hand